# Open data for software requirements

Tags: data-request, api, uses-of-open-data, metadata

I'm looking for a plattform where I can receive machine readable requirements for an application like a cms (for example firstspirit):

- Required memory
- Required hard disk capacity (depending on number of editors, number of projects, number of pages)
- Java versions
- Database
- Installation

For example:

GET http://requirements.io/api/requirements/firstspirit/8.x.x.json

```
{
    "name": "firstspririt",
    "version": "8.x.x",
    "requirements: {
        "os": ["ms-server", "debian"],
        "java": 11,
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 2):

[Libraries.io](https://libraries.io/) catalogs dependency relationships between open source projects and other project metadata for a set of supported package managers.  There is an API [here](https://libraries.io/api).